# How to do a heatMap on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The first time I'll do a heatMap in python 3 using Pandas and Matplotlib.
I tried to use the plugin gmaps in jupyter notebook.
I uploaded a csv file that conatin 2 columns (long,lat).

```
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets
gmaps.configure(api_key=os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY")
locations = gmaps.datasets.load_dataset("my_file.csv")
fig = gmaps.figure()
fig.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer(loactions))
fig
```

I got the following error:

```
    676         except KeyError:
    677             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 678             raise KeyError(key) from None
    679         return self.decodevalue(value)
    680 

KeyError: 'GOOGLE_API_KEY'
```

How can I read my file to resolve it?
Thank you

Comment: Take a look at Seaborn KDE Plot with shade = True https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html

Comment: @DanielLabbe thank you for your answer. I edited my question can you help me please to do the heatmap ?

Comment: @Dorine can you show the code where you specify 'myfile.csv' the error has to do with how your passing in that csv file. The easiest thing to do would be to just make sure the csv file is in the same directory as the python script you're running

Comment: @cgclip I edited my question  I specified my file csv in locations = gmaps.datasets.load_dataset("my_file.csv")

Comment: @cgclip is it my code wrong ?

Comment: @Dorine is the csv file in the same folder as the python script?

Comment: @DanielLabbe yes my file is in the same folder as python, I moved it now, so I got this error : gmaps.configure(api_key=os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY")
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you're missing a parenthesis at the end of that line of code. Depending on which text editor you're using it may be helpful to install a linter which is kind of like spell check for code, if you're using atom or vs code you can try installing an extension like pylint, that'll help you catch syntax errors like these

Comment: @cgclip I'm using notebook on Jupyter. I edited my question, I got an error in os.environ, I think that I should give a key API of google, no ?

Comment: @DanielLabbe Can you help me please to plot a heatMap of geolocalisation ? I edited my question to add a sample of my data (the type of my data is float not numerci I can't do it by seaborn).   Thank you

Comment: @Dorine, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are points to correct in your code. I will provide a list of what I had to do in order to put this to work in my environment (jupyter notebook).

1) Make sure to have the gmaps installed in your environment. You can achieve this by using something like:

```
pip install gmaps
```

2) In jupyter I had an issue that the js that shows the map wasn't loaded correctly. After installing the package (step 1), you have to stop all instances of jupyter and run the following command:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py gmaps
```

3) You must have a valid Google API Key, to replace the GOOGLE_API_KEY placeholder on your code. Which by the way, was missing a closing square brackets. To create your API Key, please follow the instructions from [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key). **Note that is mandatory.**

4) You don't have to import gmaps.datasets if you are working with your own file. This module loads pre-defined datasets. You can read your csv using Pandas, for instance.

The code to to perform the whole operation is:

```
import pandas as pd
import gmaps
gmaps.configure(api_key='YOUR_API_KEY') # you have to replace the value YOUR_API_KEY by the key generated in the step 3.
locations = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
fig = gmaps.figure()
fig.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer(locations))
fig
```

This produces the following map, that from my perspective I can't judge if it's correct or not.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Your file has the order of the columns Long and Lat, and the API expects Lat and Long. Changing the order made more sense for me:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer address your problem, @dorine?

Comment: @DanielLabbe , I exactly followed this but I don't see any map .No error too. Any idea why this must be happening ?